# SharePoint add-ins List View according to User Permission

Tags: list-item

I have created a list inside VS2013 SharePoint app solution which I am able to view while clicking on a link from my default.aspx page. Also have coded in JavaScript (app.js) to understand who has logged in. for eg., admin or normal user. Now I need to view this list according to the person logged in. For eg if admin, I need to view the entire list. But if its a normal user he/she must only view the list items created by him/her, not all item.
Could anyone help me understand how I could achieve this? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You want Item Level Security on a List (List Settings -> Advanced Settings)

[image]